# how to persist query result between objects in php

Tags: php, design-patterns

in my case , i have query result came from database :

the result is a array,

i want to pass result in multiple object and get result .

i try to use mediator pattern but it wont work in my case , because i need to get result from first object and pass theme to second and so on .

code:

```
$mediator->add('test',[$obj1,'methodobj1']);
$mediator->add('test',[$obj2,'methodobj2']);
$mediator->run('test','resultCameFromDataBase(array)');
```

i want somthing like this:

```
$data = $obj1($result);
$data1 = $obj2($data);
$data2 = $obj3($data1);
...
return $Result;
```

is there any advice ? should i use mediator ?

do i need to use patterns on this case ?

i know out there has many tools like doctrine2 , but in my case i cant use theme .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pipes and Filters` design pattern is what you looking for.

Take a look at https://github.com/thephpleague/pipeline which is ready to use library for your usecase.

If you need to know how it works this wiki can help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software).

I hope this helps.